# Nibbler Identification

Tags: tool-identification

I have an old drill attachment nibbler that I used 10+ years ago when I did bodywork. But the blade broke & I didn't replace it.

I'd now like to find a replacement blade, but can't identify the make/model - I've posted some images to see if anyone can help?

[image: Nibbler]

Comment: Do you have any information on the tool that goes with it?  A brand perhaps?

Comment: Nothing at all I'm afraid. There's nothing on the tool or blade :(

Comment: but the tool pictured attaches to a larger mechanical device or....it's standalone?

Comment: It attaches to a drill...

Comment: gotcha, didn't realize it was drill driven even though it's clearly in the pic.